# What is the easiest and fastest way to compare two spreadsheet files and extract maching matching data?

Tags: python, excel, linux

I have got two spreadsheet with me, Spreadsheet 1 and Spreadsheet 2.I need to extract data(rows) from spreadsheet 2 that matches spreadsheet 1. Ideally I need to get the IDs from spreadsheet 2 that has matching site names to spreadsheet 1.

```
Spreadsheet 1:

Site Name : 
10410_DL01_Patels_Foodmarket      
10700_DL01_CD_Toronta 
110190_DL13__Jonny_Mall 
110300_DL13_Ezy_Mart    
CONTINUED


Spreadsheet 2:

ID         Site Name                         Address     Upgrade
10747     10410_DL01_Patels_Foodmarket       *********   *********
32544     104658_D_Torano_fedf               ********    *********
84562     103894_Girngsdfj                   ********    ********   
10727     10700_DL01_CD_Toronta              ********    *********
42344     104658_D_Torano_fedf               ********    *********
65465     103894_Girngsdfj                   ********    ********   
32544     104658_D_Torano_fedf               ********    *********
84562     103894_Girngsdfj                   ********    ********   
10838     110190_DL13__Jonny_Mall            ********    *********
10487     110300_DL13_Ezy_Mart               ********    *********
CONTINUED
```

Comment: What format are the spread sheets saved in?  CSV, XLSX?

Comment: I can have either of these, CSV or XLSX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work, using the [xlrd](http://github.com/python-excel/xlrd) package:

```
import xlrd

# open the two spreadsheets
b1 = xlrd.open_workbook("Spreadsheet 1.xlsx")
b2 = xlrd.open_workbook("Spreadsheet 2.xlsx")

# get the first sheet from each spreadsheet
sh1 = b1.sheet_by_index(0) 
sh2 = b2.sheet_by_index(0)

# for each sheet, read each row 
for rx1 in range(sh1.nrows):
    for rx2 in range(sh2.nrows):
        # find cell values in spreadsheet 2's column 2 that 
        #   match the cell value in spreadsheet 1's column 1   
        if sh1.row(rx1)[0].value == sh2.row(rx2)[1].value:
            # print the `id` from spreadsheet 2 for this matching row
            print(sh2.row(rx2)[0].value)
```

output:

```
10747
10727
10838
10487
```

Surprisingly its fairly short, done in 9 lines of code.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Running the script, gives out the below error, even with the quatation marks on the file name:
./pythonscript.py: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./pythonscript.py: line 4: `b1 = xlrd.open_workbook(MondayList.xlsx)'

Comment: I think you may need to add quotes around your file name, like this: `b1 = xlrd.open_workbook("MondayList.xlsx")`